# Android makefile links twice

Tags: android, c++, makefile, android-ndk, linker

I've set up a makefile for my game in SDL. The template of the Application.mk file included in SDL has three architectures:

```
APP_ABI := armeabi armeabi-v7a x86
```

Everything compiles just fine for `armeabi`, but for `armeabi-v7a` it fails. To me, it looks like compilation completes, but the linker has all `obj` files of two certain folders twice. While this does not happen for `armeabi`. The linker (`ld`) gives me an error of this kind:

```
/path/to/bin/ld: error: /path/to/myObjFile.obj: multiple definition of 'foo(int, int)'
/path/to/bin/ld: /path/to/myObjFile.obj: previous definition here
```

The path is exactly the same, so this makes me assume that the linker uses every file twice. A full example of such an error is here:

```
/Users/martijncourteaux/Development/android-ndk-r10c/toolchains/arm-linux-androideabi-4.8/prebuilt/darwin-x86_64/lib/gcc/arm-linux-androideabi/4.8/../../../../arm-linux-androideabi/bin/ld: error: /Volumes/Stuff/Projects/GameDev/Gump/GumpAndroid/obj/local/armeabi-v7a/objs/main//Volumes/Stuff/Projects/GameDev/Gump/GumpAndroid/jni/src/__/ThirdParty/Box2D/Collision/b2Distance.o: multiple definition of 'b2Distance(b2DistanceOutput*, b2SimplexCache*, b2DistanceInput const*)'
/Users/martijncourteaux/Development/android-ndk-r10c/toolchains/arm-linux-androideabi-4.8/prebuilt/darwin-x86_64/lib/gcc/arm-linux-androideabi/4.8/../../../../arm-linux-androideabi/bin/ld: /Volumes/Stuff/Projects/GameDev/Gump/GumpAndroid/obj/local/armeabi-v7a/objs/main//Volumes/Stuff/Projects/GameDev/Gump/GumpAndroid/jni/src/__/ThirdParty/Box2D/Collision/b2Distance.o: previous definition here
```

However, the object files that are linked double also generate this warning when I launch `ndk-build`:

```
/Users/martijncourteaux/Development/android-ndk-r10c/build/core/build-binary.mk:449: warning: ignoring old commands for target `/Volumes/Stuff/Projects/GameDev/Gump/GumpAndroid/obj/local/armeabi-v7a/objs/main//Volumes/Stuff/Projects/GameDev/Gump/GumpAndroid/jni/src/__/ThirdParty/Collision/b2Distance.o'
/Users/martijncourteaux/Development/android-ndk-r10c/build/core/build-binary.mk:449: warning: overriding commands for target `/Volumes/Stuff/Projects/GameDev/Gump/GumpAndroid/obj/local/armeabi-v7a/objs/main//Volumes/Stuff/Projects/GameDev/Gump/GumpAndroid/jni/src/__/ThirdParty/Collision/b2Distance.o'
```

Note that I have the impression that all these `obj`-files that have these `multiple definition` errors generate also generate this warning.

This is my `Application.mk`:

```
APP_STL := gnustl_static
APP_ABI := armeabi armeabi-v7a x86
NDK_TOOLCHAIN_VERSION := clang
APP_CPPFLAGS += -std=c++11
APP_PLATFORM := android-10
```

And here is my `Android.mk`:

```
LOCAL_PATH := $(call my-dir)

include $(CLEAR_VARS)

LOCAL_MODULE := main

SDL_PATH := ../SDL
THIRD_PARTY_FOLDER := $(LOCAL_PATH)/../ThirdParty

LOCAL_CPPFLAGS += -frtti
LOCAL_CPPFLAGS += -fexceptions
LOCAL_CPPFLAGS += -funwind-tables

PCH_FILE := $(LOCAL_PATH)/Gump/Gump-Prefix.pch
#PCH_FILE := Gump/Gump-Prefix.pch
LOCAL_CPPFLAGS += -include $(PCH_FILE) 

#LOCAL_PCH := $(PCH_FILE)
#LOCAL_CPPFLAGS += -DPCH

LOCAL_C_INCLUDES := $(LOCAL_PATH)/$(SDL_PATH)/include \
                    $(LOCAL_PATH)/$(SDL_PATH)_mixer/ \
                    $(LOCAL_PATH)/$(SDL_PATH)_image/ \
                    $(LOCAL_PATH)/$(SDL_PATH)_net/ \
                    $(LOCAL_PATH)/../ThirdParty/ \
                    $(LOCAL_PATH)/Gump/

# Add your application source files here...
GUMP_SRC_FILES := $(wildcard $(LOCAL_PATH)/Gump/*.cpp)
THIRD_PARTY_SRC_FILES += $(wildcard $(THIRD_PARTY_FOLDER)/tinyxml2/tinyxml2.cpp)

THIRD_PARTY_SRC_FILES += $(wildcard $(THIRD_PARTY_FOLDER)/Box2D/*/*.cpp)
THIRD_PARTY_SRC_FILES += $(wildcard $(THIRD_PARTY_FOLDER)/Box2D/*/*/*.cpp)

THIRD_PARTY_SRC_FILES += $(wildcard $(THIRD_PARTY_FOLDER)/poly2tri/**/*.cc)

LOCAL_SRC_FILES := $(SDL_PATH)/src/main/android/SDL_android_main.c $(THIRD_PARTY_SRC_FILES) $(GUMP_SRC_FILES)

LOCAL_SHARED_LIBRARIES := SDL2_image SDL2_mixer SDL2_net SDL2 

LOCAL_LDLIBS := -lGLESv1_CM -lGLESv2 -llog

include $(BUILD_SHARED_LIBRARY)
```

---

**My Guess (turns out false):**

After writing this question and looking closely to provide you guys the most accurate information as possible about my problem, I noticed that the obj-files that are giving errors are those were I've used a wildcard on folder level as well. Eg: `$(ROOT)/*/*.cpp`. While these wildcards give no problem: `$(ROOT)/Gump/*.cpp`. I don't know for sure, but I guess that the wildcards work different on when linking for these different architectures...

**Update:**

I've tested it again not using wildcards for folders, and the same error about multiple definition appears.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your list of files is appended every time a new ABI is being built. `LOCAL_SRC_FILES` is erased through `include $(CLEAR_VARS)`; `GUMP_SRC_FILES` is redefined each time. But `THIRD_PARTY_SRC_FILES` only grows longer and longer. This has nothing to do with the wildcards, as you noticed. Simply add line

```
THIRD_PARTY_SRC_FILES :=
```

after `include $(CLEAR_VARS)`, and your build will be fine.

Comment: Genius! I'll remember that :)

Answer (score 0):

Running `ndk-build V=1` shows the build commands executed during the process. There I could see the `.o` files being linked twice. I'm not sure what the reason for that is. I guess it might have been due to the fact that the android makefile in the `src/` folder used sources from his parent directory: `../ThirdParty/[morehere]`.

I fixed it by creating extra makefiles for these third party libraries, so now every library creates a shared library in a .so file. Which gets linked at compile-time. I think this is neater, because changing a makefile requires only that subproject to be recompiled.